# PyMongo .find(data) to return all objs with key and value

Tags: python, pymongo

I have a database with orders, I want to search for `data = {"user": "Bob"}` and return all documents with `data`.

I tried doing

```py
data = {"user": "Bob"}
order_list = orders.find(data)
for order in order_list:
    print(order)
```

but it just gives back an empty cursor, when I do list(orders.find(data)) it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are connecting to right database. If you don't specify a database, the default database of `test` will be used. I would recommed always declaring a db variable with the specific database selected as per `mydatabase` in this example:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

db = MongoClient()['mydatabase']
orders = db.orders

data = {"user": "Bob"}

orders.insert_one(data)

order_list = orders.find(data)
for order in order_list:
    print(order)
```

prints:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5fba78111e5694dd7fddbe3d'), 'user': 'Bob'}
```